# Communicating to an iso 14443 card with android nfc

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, nfc, apdu

I have been trying to write a basic android app that could send APDUs to an ISO 14443 card and receive response APDUs. I already have my applet in the smart card with ID F000000A. So far I have written/modified other codes but I know im doing something wrong as my app crashes on my phone as I try to launch it. Below is my code just to mention. I have my Isodep transceiver in a different class and also my isodep adapter in a different class.

**IsodepAdapter**:

```
package kitkat.com.example.kaudi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IsoDepAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>(100);
    private int messageCounter;

    public IsoDepAdapter(LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    }

    public void addMessage(String message) {
        messageCounter++;
        messages.add("Message [" + messageCounter + "]: " + message);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages == null ? 0 : messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        TextView view = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        view.setText((CharSequence)getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Isodeptransceive:**

```
package kitkat.com.example.kaudi;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;

public class IsoDepTransceiver implements Runnable {
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        void onMessage(byte[] message);
        void onError(Exception exception);
    }

    private IsoDep isoDep;
    private OnMessageReceived onMessageReceived;

    public IsoDepTransceiver(IsoDep isoDep, OnMessageReceived onMessageReceived) {
        this.isoDep = isoDep;
        this.onMessageReceived = onMessageReceived;
    }

    private static final byte[] CLA_INS_P1_P2 = { 0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04, 0x00 };
    private static final byte[] AID_ANDROID = { (byte)0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A };

    private byte[] createSelectAidApdu(byte[] aid) {
        byte[] result = new byte[6 + aid.length];
        System.arraycopy(CLA_INS_P1_P2, 0, result, 0, CLA_INS_P1_P2.length);
        result[4] = (byte)aid.length;
        System.arraycopy(aid, 0, result, 5, aid.length);
        result[result.length - 1] = 0;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int messageCounter = 0;
        try {
            isoDep.connect();
            byte[] response = isoDep.transceive(createSelectAidApdu(AID_ANDROID));
            while (isoDep.isConnected() && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                String message = "Message from IsoDep " + messageCounter++;
                response = isoDep.transceive(message.getBytes());
                onMessageReceived.onMessage(response);
            }
            isoDep.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            onMessageReceived.onError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**NfcReader:**

```
package kitkat.com.example.kaudi;

import kitkat.com.example.kaudi.IsoDepTransceiver.OnMessageReceived;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NfcReader extends Activity implements OnMessageReceived, ReaderCallback {
    private static String TAG = NfcReader.class.getSimpleName();
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refTextView);

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, null);
    }

    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HCEfound"); 
        IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);
        IsoDepTransceiver transceiver = new IsoDepTransceiver(isoDep, this);
        transceiver.run();    
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessage(final byte[] message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String readFromHce = new String(message);
                TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refTextView);
                result.setText(readFromHce);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception exception) {
        onMessage(exception.getMessage().getBytes());
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kitkat.com.example.kaudi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="kitkat.com.example.kaudi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
             </intent-filter>
             <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                        android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**LogCat (error)**

```
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): Process: kitkat.com.example.kaudi, PID: 5247
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kitkat.com.example.kaudi/kitkat.com.example.kaudi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kitkat.com.example.kaudi.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kitkat.com.example.kaudi-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/kitkat.com.example.kaudi-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kitkat.com.example.kaudi.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kitkat.com.example.kaudi-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/kitkat.com.example.kaudi-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
05-03 19:54:58.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5247):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your code (paste the code into your question instead of linking (actually you did not even *link* them) images. Also post the error (stacktrace?) you get when your app crashes.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Hi..thanks for replying...i have done so...i previously thought it will look too messy :)

Comment: Also note that (particularly if you are using a Java Card, but with many other smartcards too), you might run into problems if you are trying to use an AID of less than 5 bytes and if you try to exchange "APDUs" that are not well formed according to ISO 7816-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post any code for an activity named `kitkat.com.example.kaudi.MainActivity`. As the exception indicates exactly this -- there is no activity named `MainActivity` on your class path -- I assume that you actually wanted to declare `kitkat.com.example.kaudi.NfcReader` in your manifest.

Comment: Yes...you are right...now my app doesn't crash...but unfortunately i am not in possession of my card at the moment to try...Pls i have another question...after running the app from eclipse...how do i send subsequent commands..is it from apdutool.bat?? i appreciate it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You send commands from your Android app to a card by using the `IsoDep.transceive(...)` method.

Comment: im sorry but i dont quite get it...after building and running the app...is it possible to adit code and send apdus...or do i make some interface in the app where apdus will be typed and sent...sorry for my stupidity..

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with fundamental design decisions in your app. You would typically design that according to *your* needs. If you need to manually type APDUs, then you would certainly need to design a UI for that. Though, letting the user type APDUs while holding a card to the device won't be a good idea from a usability point of view.